# D3 for rotating labels by 90 in pie chart

Tags: d3.js, rotation, heatmap

I am trying to rotate labels in a pie chart made using d3.
The script is not working however, the labels are horizontal and overlapping.

```
            labels.selectAll("text")        
            .data(segmentLabels).enter()
            .append("text")
            .append("textPath")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#segment-label-path-"+id)

            .style("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {return i * 100 / numSegments + "%";} )


                .text(function(d) {return d;});
    });
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the labels vertical? Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/vigorousnorth/7331bb51d4f0c2ae0314

Comment: The link bl.ocks.org/vigorousnorth/7331bb51d4f0c2ae0314 is not working.